# Evaluate The Indefinite Integral With U-Sub

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I can't get beyond the u-sub in this problem, here's what i've tried:

$\int{x^2\sqrt{2+x}}dx$

Let $u=\sqrt{2+x}$

Let $z = 2 + x$

$du = (z)'(\sqrt{z})'dx$ <- Chain Rule

$du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+x}}dx$

How do I solve from here?

Comment: I understand how to do that part - what I do not understand is how they get to that point after I have $du$ where does $(u^2-2)^2$ come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{2+x}$. Then notice that $u^2 = 2+x$. Differentiating this (implicitly via chain rule) yields $2u \, du = dx$. Furthermore, observe that $x = u^2 - 2$. Hence, substituting all of this yields:
$$
\int (x)^2(\sqrt{2+x}) \, (dx)
= \int (u^2 - 2)^2(u)(2u \, du)
= 2\int u^2(u^2 - 2)^2 \, du
$$
From there, you can expand and integrate with some tedious but simple arithmetic.

Comment: Ahh - that makes sense, I didn't think to square it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Just expand $(u^2-2)^2$ and multiply through by $u^2$, then take the integral. All the terms should be elementary integrands.

Comment: Expanding then finding the anti-derivatives is the easy part - where does $(u^2-2)^2$ come from?